# Kubuntu 20.04 not sending emails from cron

Tags: cron, email, ssmtp

I'm new to Kubuntu (installed 20.04 about 4 weeks ago). I am having a problem with cron jobs not sending emails. I know that I have to have an MTA, so I installed and configured ssmtp. I also installed postfix but later removed it.

When I run this command:

`ls -al /usr/lib/sendmail`

it show me this output:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Feb 24  2020 /usr/lib/sendmail -> ../sbin/sendmail`

When I run this command:

`ls -al /usr/lib/sendmail`

it shows me this output

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Feb 24  2020 /usr/lib/sendmail -> ../sbin/sendmail`

So, these 2 commands tell me that sendmail is properly pointing to ssmtp, which I would expect since sendmail is not installed.

I know that ssmtp is properly configure because I can send an email using a mail command similar to this:

`echo "test from myname@myhostname to myname@mydomain.com" | mail -s "test from myname@myhostname" myname@mydomain.com`

The output from the above command is received by my mail program (I'm using Evolution).

I have a crontab file with lines similar to these:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAILTO="myname@mydomain.com"
* * * * * date &
```

According to all the posts I have read, I would expect the above crontab definition to send the output from the date command to the email address specified in the MAILTO statement. But I never get any of these emails. I've checked /var/log/cron.log and I know that the cron task does get executed. I've also checked var/log/mail.log and I know that the email is not sent. I've also checked var/log/mail.err and know that there are no errors posted.

I have figured out a work around to force cron to send an email. I changed the cron task definition line to look like this:

`* * * * * date | mail -s "cron date myname@myhostname" myname@mydomain.com &`

In this case, cron does send the email and Evolution receives.

I do not understand why cron is failing to send the email when I don't include `| mail -s "cron date myname@myhostname" myname@mydomain.com` as part of statement.

I've been working on this issue for days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

it-man

Comment: I wonder if it's because you put the `date` command into the background (with `&`) causing it to buffer its output indefinitely?

Comment: steeldriver, thanks SO much for the suggestion. I removed the "&" and in fact that did allow the output from cron to emailed out. So this solved the problem. VERY strange. I came from using openSUSE for about 10 years and the "&" had no affect on sending email from cron in that environment. Now I'm curious why this solved the problem.

Comment: Actually I'm now not sure it is related to buffering - I'm really not sure why backgrounding the command has this effect. Nevertheless, AFAIK each cron job is executed asynchronously so I don't see any reason to use `&`